# BNC Male to Cable Connector Proper Method

Tags: connector, cables, bnc

I've recently bought some cheap RG58/59/6 BNC male-to-cable connectors for DIY work. The connector qnd its guts look like this:

[image: BNC connector assembled] [image: BNC connector four parts]

I couldn't find a proper name for this connector type, even worse, I couldn't find any assembly procedure either (there are videos for crimp and twist on etc. types). Can anyone explain (supporting visuals will be appreciated :) ) how should a RG6 coaxial cable be mounted to this connector? (the part with 4 teeth ruined the shielding foil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This TV coax illustration is the closest I could find but illustrates the method.

[image]

*Source: [Electronics 2000](https://www.electronics2000.co.uk/pin-out/rfconns.php).*

> ... the part with 4 teeth ruined the shielding foil.

The teeth clamp the folded-back screen and insulation. They don't bite the foil. Insert the cable through the teeth end.

Comment: Hmm that looks like the actual intended method, will try! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find on how to assemble these is [this link](http://www.cctv101.co.uk/cctv-bnc-screw-on-connector-for-rg59-rg6-cable.html), namely:

> 1) Strip and cut the video run of your cable.
>
> 2) Screw off piece (4) to reveal pieces (2) and (3) inside.
>
> 3) Slide piece (4) over the end of your prepared cable.
>
> 4) Pry open the teeth on piece (3) then slide it over your prepared
>   cable, leaving it sitting flush with the outer jacket. Using your
>   fingers, push the teeth down, tightening their grip against the cable
>   jacket.
>
> 5) Undo the screw on piece (2) and use gentle force to push in the
>   centre conductor in, then tighten the screw.
>
> 6) Slide over the the main connector (1) back on until it mates with
>   piece (4) and gently screw the connector until it is secure.

Comment: "sitting flush with the outer jacket" that I did wrong, I thought it'd go under the jacket like the crimp types. Problem solved, thanks!